# How do you acess a property of a bean for reading in a spring xml config file?

Tags: spring

I want to do something like the following in spring:

```
<beans>
    ...
    <bean id="bean1" ... />
    <bean id="bean2">
        <property name="propName" value="bean1.foo" />
...
```

I would think that this would access the getFoo() method of bean1 and call the setPropName() method of bean2, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I understood:

1. You have a bean (bean1) with a
   property called "foo"
2. You have another bean (bean2) with a
   property named "propName", wich also
   has to have the same "foo" that in
   bean1.

why not doing this:

```
<beans>
...
<bean id="foo" class="foopackage.foo"/>
<bean id="bean1" class="foopackage.bean1">
  <property name="foo" ref="foo"/>
</bean> 
<bean id="bean2" class="foopackage.bean2">
  <property name="propName" ref="foo"/>
</bean>
....
</beans>
```

Doing this, your bean2 is not coupled to bean1 like in your example. You can change bean1 and bean2 without affecting each other.

If you **REALLY** need to do the injection you proposed, you can use:

```
<util:property-path id="propName" path="bean1.foo"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [PropertyPathFactoryBean](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPathFactoryBean.html):

```
    <bean id="bean2" depends-on="bean1">
        <property name="propName">
            <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean">
                <property name="targetBeanName" value="bean1"/>
                <property name="propertyPath" value="foo"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: An alternate syntax uses the "id" attribute to set the target bean name and property path.

   <bean id="bean1.foo" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean">

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to inject bean1, then get `foo` manually because of a timing issue. When does the framework resolve the value of the target bean?

You could create a pointer bean and configure that.

```
class SpringRef {
  private String targetProperty;
  private Object targetBean;

  //getters/setters

  public Object getValue() {
    //resolve the value of the targetProperty on targetBean. 
  }
}
```

[Common-BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) should be helpful.